# Flutter: running the app on the IOS simulator throwing Podfile error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ios-simulator, podfile

I am developing a mobile application using Flutter. I am a beginner to Flutter and not familiar with iOS development either. I am using Android Studio as my IDE for development. Now, I am trying to run my app on the IOS simulator running the following command.

```
flutter run
```

When I did, I got the following error.

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
    `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I checked the link mentioned in the link and it was not very helpful to me. Which files in the project do I have to modify to fix the error? Which settings do I have to change?

I tried uncommenting this line "platform :ios, '9.0'" in the Podfile. I am still getting the following error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              1.6s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `appspector` from `.symlinks/plugins/appspector/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_macos/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "appspector":
      In Podfile:
        appspector (from `.symlinks/plugins/appspector/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `appspector (from `.symlinks/plugins/appspector/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 0):

The appspector IOS SDK version is above of your project IOS SDK version. Change your project IOS SDK version to be at least the same of appspector, and it will work.